# Firebase fails to send message to database in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, firebase

Hi there I am building an application that uses Firebase messaging.The application is a asp.net Mvc application and I am using visual studio 2015.Tried following the documentation but it still doesn't work. When I enter the name and message in the view and hit the enter button nothing happens nothing is displayed on the screen or entered in the database. I am just wondering where have I gone wrong with my set up thanks for the help guys.

My View

```
<h2>firebase</h2>
<!-- CHAT MARKUP -->
<div class="example-chat l-demo-container">
  <header>Firebase Chat Demo</header>

  <div class='example-chat-toolbar'>
    <label for="nameInput">Username:</label>
    <input type='text' id='nameInput' placeholder='enter a username...'>
  </div>

  <ul id='example-messages' class="example-chat-messages"></ul>

  <footer>
    <input type='text' id='messageInput'  placeholder='Type a message...'>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Bundleconfig

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/firebase", "https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js").Include("~/Scripts/firebase.js"));
```

Scripts Folder firebase,js

```
// CREATE A REFERENCE TO FIREBASE
var messagesRef = new Firebase('MyFirebaseLinkIsHere');

// REGISTER DOM ELEMENTS
var messageField = $('#messageInput');
var nameField = $('#nameInput');
var messageList = $('#example-messages');

// LISTEN FOR KEYPRESS EVENT
messageField.keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        //FIELD VALUES
        var username = nameField.val();
        var message = messageField.val();

        //SAVE DATA TO FIREBASE AND EMPTY FIELD
        messagesRef.push({ name: username, text: message });
        messageField.val('');
    }
});

// Add a callback that is triggered for each chat message.
messagesRef.limitToLast(10).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
    //GET DATA
    var data = snapshot.val();
    var username = data.name || "anonymous";
    var message = data.text;

    //CREATE ELEMENTS MESSAGE & SANITIZE TEXT
    var messageElement = $("<li>");
    var nameElement = $("<strong class='example-chat-username'></strong>")
    nameElement.text(username);
    messageElement.text(message).prepend(nameElement);

    //ADD MESSAGE
    messageList.append(messageElement)

    //SCROLL TO BOTTOM OF MESSAGE LIST
    messageList[0].scrollTop = messageList[0].scrollHeight;
});
```

_Layout

```
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/firebase")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)


        @RenderBody()
```

Comment: If you put a `console.log('here')` in the `messageField.keypress(function (e) {` function, does it log?

Comment: Hi I added some alerts and nothing popped up

Comment: So then it looks like your jQuery `messageField.keypress()` handler is not being invoked. I'm pretty sure that removes C#, ASP.NET and Firebase from the equation. You might want to try and set up an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that uses just jQuery.